# 9-patch image not getting recognized

Tags: android, nine-patch

i tried to create a 9-patch image to use as a background in a `RelativeLayout` containing a `ListView`. The 9-patch is working fine in the eclipse preview, but if i test it on a real device or bluestacks (emulator) the image just gets used as it is. With all the borders. I already checked for errors with the 9patchtool or resaved it. But nothing worked.

Is there something wrong with my image?

[image: 9-patch-image]

And here is how i define my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="0dip">
```

If you need any more info or even code...just let me know...Thanks in advance

EDIT: Some clarifications: The filename is bg.9.png and it is in the drawable-mdpi folder. I am using a Galaxy S (480×800) for testing (don't now the exact density at the moment, but the drawable-mdpi folder worked fine till now - even with other 9-patch images). And the grey border is just the background of the 9-patch tool where i took the screenshot from, it isn't acutally in the image.

Comment: your file do end in .9.png, right ?

Comment: Is that image the actual 9-patch? If so, it appears to have an extra border around it.

Comment: could be it is resampled for size at some point. In which drawable folder is it, and what is the size/density of your device ?

Comment: Edited my post to clarify some things.

Comment: Galaxy S firsty reads from hdpi. Have you tried to copy your image to hdpi folder?

Comment: Put a copy in every drawable folder - nothing changed :(

Comment: I had a similar issue once. I solved it by renaming the ninepatch. It sounds silly but it worked for me.

Comment: Do you get any compiler errors? AFAIK you're only allowed a single stretchable area (i.e. only one black line in the top and left sides). I know you're trying to get only the 'non-torn' bits of the image to stretch, but that's not allowed at the moment, even though it can appear to work in the 9-path editor.